# Elementary Proof on Perfect Squares.

Tags: proof-writing, radicals, square-numbers

The Proof I'm working on is:
If $r \in \mathbb{N}$ is not a perfect square, then $\sqrt{r}$ is irrational.\

The farthest I've gotten is by proving by contradiction, assuming that $\sqrt{r}$ is rational. Could anyone let me know if I'm on the right track or give me a bit of a hand. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you accept the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, that every number has a unique prime factorisation?

Comment: If you have a proof by contradiction, then you have a proof. Let's see that.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes

Comment: If $r$ isn't a square of an integer but $r=(m/n)^2$ then $rn^2=m^2$. There's a prime that appears an odd number of times in the prime factorisation of one side, and an even number of times on the other side.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks a lot this all makes sense now. Reached this step before but wasn't thinking about factorization!